# Using SO questions/answers to track application/framework popularity

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

When looking at new tools I use Stack Overflow to make an informal guess as to its user base in the real world. A small number of questions likely means low usage, which means I'm not going to invest a lot of time in something not many people are using.

Is there a site/tool that helps me do that, or should I 'roll my own' via SEDE?

Comment: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends

Comment: It might also mean that the technology documents itself and needs little questions, I would **definitely** use something like that ;) (chance of it being the case:  non-existent)